# QTMovieModernizer errors

Tags: objective-c, quicktime, qtkit

I'm trying to write a piece of code that would "modernize" a video file. This is the code :

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [[NSOpenPanel alloc] init];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

if([openPanel runModal] == NSCancelButton)
     return;
NSMutableString *destination = [[[openPanel URL] absoluteString] mutableCopy];
[destination appendString:@"/"];
[destination appendString:[self fileName:[url absoluteString] withExtention:NO]];
[destination appendString:@".m4v"];

QTMovieModernizer *modernizer = [[QTMovieModernizer alloc] initWithSourceURL:url destinationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:destination]];

[modernizer modernizeWithCompletionHandler:^{NSLog(@"Modernization complete to file %@ - error : %@",[modernizer destinationURL],[modernizer error]);}];
```

The problem is that I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException`. I've checked the source and destination url carefully and they seem to be ok. The error seems to happen at the initialization the `QTMovieModernizer` instance. What can be going wrong here?

---

Error details :

```
 NSInvalidArgumentException
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82cdc25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff84c8ae75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   QTKit                               0x00007fff84fc4303 -[QTMovieModernizer createUniqueLegacyFilePath:extension:inDirectory:] + 0
3   MediaPlayer                         0x0000000100003bb9 -[AppDelegate modernize:] + 1097
4   MediaPlayer                         0x000000010000536f -[AppDelegate openFile:] + 879
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8339d340 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 327
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff833b82a8 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 394
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff833b7fe4 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 117
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8340748d -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] + 35
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff83407309 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] + 104
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff833ae0d6 NSSLMMenuEventHandler + 716
11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b7d21d4 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 892
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b7d1787 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 385
13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b7e5880 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b81b640 _ZL18SendHICommandEventjPK9HICommandjjhPKvP20OpaqueEventTargetRefS5_PP14OpaqueEventRef + 420
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b84e238 SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 59
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b84e1e0 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 178
17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b84e0bf _ZL19FinishMenuSelectionP13SelectionDataP10MenuResultS2_ + 94
18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b856095 _ZL14MenuSelectCoreP8MenuData5PointdjPP13OpaqueMenuRefPt + 718
19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b855cc1 _HandleMenuSelection2 + 446
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8332073c _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 284
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8317f6be _DPSNextEvent + 2170
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8317ea2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff83172b2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8315d913 NSApplicationMain + 940
25  MediaPlayer                         0x0000000100008362 main + 34
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff830d95fd start + 1
27  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
   )
```

---

EDIT :

I found out that `-fileName:withExtension:` returns a string by replacing `%20` by spaces. After handling this, the exception at the initsilizing is gone but instead, I have the following error when converting the file :

```
  <<<< QTMovieModernizer >>>> FigFormatUtilsCreateFormatReader: Error -12848 from       FigFormatReaderCreateForStream
  <<<< QTMovieModernizer >>>> formatReaderForSourceURL: Error in FormatReaderForSourceURL: -12848
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: @rmaddy that's the full error message just `An uncaught exception was raised` before this.

Comment: if you can print out the full source & destination URL's, what do they look like?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the variable are here : `destination __NSCFString * @"file:///Users/Moray/Desktop//S1%20E01%20-%20My%20First%20Day.m4v" 0x0000608000a75240`, `url NSURL * @"file:///Users/Moray/Movies/Scrubs/Season%201/S1%20E01%20-%20My%20First%20Day.avi" 0x000060000067a340`